# Norm and differentiability

Tags: analysis

How to prove that norm in a real Inner product space is function of class $C^{\infty}$ and 
$$\|\cdot \|'' (x) (h_1 , h_2)=\frac{1}{\|x\|} (h_1 | h_2)-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3} (x | h_1)(x | h_2)$$

I know that the norm is differentiable at $x \neq 0$ and 
$$\|\cdot \|' (x) (h)=\frac{1}{\|x\|} (x | h)$$
and function $$(h_1,h_2) \to \frac{1}{\|x\|} (h_1 | h_2)-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3} (x | h_1)(x | h_2)$$ is continuous and bilinear. Please help me.

But $X$ is an arbitrary real inner product space, not only $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: A norm isn't differentiable at the origin.

Comment: @Falcon correct but it is clear that he wants the derivative elsewhere (he is dividing by the norm). Shouldn't he compute the derivative of the inner product as well?

Comment: His statement is a real euclidean norm is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$, it should be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Proposition 1.** $\|.\|$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\})$.

**Proof.** $t\in\mathbb{R}_+^*\mapsto\sqrt{t}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R_+^*})$ and $\|\cdot\|:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+^*$, it suffices to prove that $\|.\|^2$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

One has: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\forall h\in\mathbb{R}^n,\mathrm{d}_x\|\cdot\|^2.h=2\langle x,h\rangle.$$
Indeed, one has: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle.$$
Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore, for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one gets: $$\|x+h\|^2-\|h\|^2=2\langle x,h\rangle.$$
$h\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto 2\langle x,h\rangle$ is a linear map and $\|x+h\|^2-\|h\|^2-2\langle x,h\rangle=o(\|h\|)$, hence the result.

$\mathrm{d}\|\cdot\|^2:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathrm{d}_x\|\cdot\|^2\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$ is a linear map and hence is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. $\|\cdot\|^2$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. $\Box$

> **Proposition 2.** For all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ and for all $(h,k)\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^2$, one has: $${\mathrm{d}^2}_x\|\cdot\|(h,k)=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\langle h,k\rangle-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3}\langle x,h\rangle\langle x,k\rangle.$$

**Proof.** Let $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, one has: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\},(\partial_i\|\cdot\|)(x)=\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}.$$
Indeed, let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one has: $$\|x\|=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n{x_i}^2}.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$(\partial_i\|\cdot\|)(x)=\frac{2x_i}{\displaystyle 2\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n{x_i}^2}}.$$
Hence the result.

Let $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one gets: $$({\partial^2}_{i,j}\|\cdot\|)(x)=\frac{(\partial_ix_j)\|x\|-(\partial_i\|.\|)(x)x_j}{\|x\|^2}=\frac{\delta_{i,j}}{\|x\|}-\frac{x_ix_j}{\|x\|^3}.$$
Therefore, for $(h,k)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one has: $$\begin{align}{\mathrm{d}^2}_x\|\cdot\|(h,k)&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n({\partial^2}_{i,j}\|\cdot\|)(x)h_ik_j\\&=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\sum_{i=1}^nh_ik_i-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^nx_ix_jh_ik_j\\&=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\langle h,k\rangle-\frac{1}{\|x\|^3}\langle x,h\rangle\langle x,k\rangle.\Box\end{align}$$

Comment: But $X$ is an arbitrary real inner product space, not $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I think $X$ is finite-dimensional, isn't it?

Comment: the norm is differentiable at $x \neq 0$ and 
$$\|\cdot \|' (x) (h)=\frac{1}{\|x\|} (x | h)$$ and $X$ can be infinite-dimensional

Comment: If $X$ is infinite-dimensional, proposition 1 holds, since for all $x$, $h\mapsto 2\langle x,h\rangle$ is continuous using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For proposition 2, obviously you cannot use partial derivatives (which was just a quick way to do it).

Comment: How to show that
How to show that
$\frac{\frac{1}{\|x+h_1\|} (x+h_2 | h_1-\frac{1}{\|x\|} (x | h_1))- \frac{1}{\|x\|} (h_1 | h_2)+\frac{1}{\|x\|^3} (x | h_1)(x | h_2)}{\|h_2\|} \to 0$